# SQL Server : Group Customers and Subscription

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this. As you can see Customer ID `0` has Subscription ID `000`, Customer ID `1` has Subscriptions `001`, `002` and `003`. Since Subscription `003` is also attached to Customer ID `2`, they are related. Think of it as a family taking subscriptions. An individual family member with his/her own individual IDs can have multiple subscriptions and/or also be a part of someone else's subscription in the same family.

[image]

```sql
with cte as
(
select '000' as Subscription, 0 as Customer
union all
select '001' as Subscription, 1 as Customer
union all
select '002' as Subscription, 1 as Customer
union all
select '003' as Subscription, 1 as Customer
union all
select '003' as Subscription, 2 as Customer
union all
select '004' as Subscription, 2 as Customer
union all
select '005' as Subscription, 3 as Customer
union all
select '006' as Subscription, 4 as Customer
union all
select '006' as Subscription, 5 as Customer
union all
select '007' as Subscription, 1 as Customer
)
select * from cte
```

One thing to note is that the Customer and the Subscription IDs will not be in order.

What I want is the following table as an output. I want to be able to relate the subscriptions with related customers and customers with related subscriptions together. In a way, I want to assign an unique ID to each family.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you supply your sample data in a consumable format, *not* an image please?

Comment: @Larnu Apologies, updated the Question with a SQLFiddle link

Comment: Do not use Image as sample data PLEASE.

Comment: I've put the sample data into the question for you. Side note, you do know that SQL Server has supported `VALUES` table constructs since at *least* 2008, right? No need to use that old `UNION ALL` syntax for such things anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a new column in your table.

If you only need the results once then this will let you away but the group Ids may be different depending on the table data:

```
     select subscription, customer, 
    (select top 1 customer 
    from cte cte2 
    where cte2.subscription = cte.subscription
order by customer) as Group
        from cte
        order by subscription, customer
```

If you need the group higher than 0 then add 1 within the embedded select:

```
    select subscription, customer, 
        (select top 1 customer + 1
        from cte cte2 
        where cte2.subscription = cte.subscription
order by customer) as group
            from cte
            order by subscription, customer
```

Comment: I do not want the customer column again, What I want is a unique ID for each related information. the values in the Group column are sample, not based on the customer column

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `Lag` functions and combine them to find the change for a group like below:

```
;with cte as
(
select *
from 
(
    values('000' , 0),('001' , 1),('002' , 1),('003' , 1),('003' , 2),('004' , 2),('005' , 3),('006' , 4),('006' , 5),('007' , 7)
)as t (Subscription, Customer)
)
, cte2 as
(
    select *,case when (lag(Subscription) over (order by (select null))) = Subscription then 0 else 1 end change_sub
    ,case when (lag(Customer) over (order by (select null))) = Customer then 0 else 1 end change_cust
    from cte
)
, cte3 as
(
    select *, change_sub & change_cust comb_change from cte2
)

select Subscription, Customer, (select sum(comb_change) from cte3 where Subscription <= t.Subscription) Final_Group
from cte3 t
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aac8fe6283a12ea4e99b16c1b79d58f8)**.

Comment: Thanks @sacse, but it doesnt work if the subscription or the customers are out of order. e.g., if you change the customer for `007` to 1, it doesnt appear in group 2. it creates its own group

Comment: @KrazzyNefarious right, because I thought there is some order in the Subscription/Customer column based on the given data.

Comment: I wished it was in order, but its the just sample that I am showing here, The Subscription column are a bigint and the Customer column is a numeric(24,0) and they are not in any specific order

Comment: @KrazzyNefarious Please add different scenarios to the question as well so that one can think of all points before diving in. I think if there is no specific order, defining groups might be a lengthy process.

Comment: @KrazzyNefarious does [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67a1d69f608fda65f58403443043e949) solve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no, in your example, Subscription `006` has customers 1 and 5, so both of them should be in Group 2 (same as customer 1)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Using the previous values for both the customer and the subscription to group the lists orders the values as you wanted.

```
SELECT  Subscription,
        Customer, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Customer <> PrevCust AND Subscription = PrevSub then 0 
                   WHEN Customer <> PrevCust  THEN 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY  Customer) [Group]
FROM
(
    select *, LAG(Subscription,1, '') OVER(PARTITION BY Subscription ORDER BY Customer) PrevSub
        ,LAG(Customer,1, -1) OVER(ORDER BY Customer) PrevCust
    from cte
) X
```